# SQL Insert else Update not working

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I'm trying to write a sql statement that does an insert if a certain row id doesn't exist else updates.
So I've read and the below should work however it just freezes my SQLite database browser:

Any ideas?

```
INSERT INTO details
 (id, name, age)
VALUES
 (“1”, "mike", "22")
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 name = “mike”
 age = “22”
```

Comment: at the very least, you need a comma between the two fields after the duplicate

Comment: Use single or double quotes in the DUPLICATE part,you have something else now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to find current posts on the subject, but it appears that "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" does not exist in sqlite. you'll need to find an alternate way to do it. the two methods i've found are

1) ON CONFLICT...REPLACE http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html which doesn't update but deletes the given row then inserts it with the new values and

2) try/catch clause, something like this: http://blog.client9.com/2007/11/21/sqlite3-and-on-duplicate-key-update.html which is programmatically catching the error from the conflict, and enacting the update when the error occurs

Comment: Thanks mate! All i needed was INSERT OR REPLACE